# zsh HISTFILE - still read from ~/.zsh_history

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I set my `$HISTFILE` env var to something custom, and my zsh is indeed writing to the new histfile.

But when using up-arrow or other history-searching capabilities, **it still reads from ~/.zsh_history**.

**Ie if I open a new shell, and press up-arrow directly, I will get the last line written to `~/.zsh_history`** :(

I use oh-my-zsh (with `osx brew celery gem git-flow npm pip screen vi-mode last-working-dir docker`), and here are the setopts that I use:

```
# zsh options
#Initial
setopt appendhistory autocd beep extendedglob nomatch notify
#history
HISTSIZE=100000000
SAVEHIST=100000000
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
setopt extended_history
setopt hist_expire_dups_first
setopt hist_ignore_dups # ignore duplication command history list
setopt hist_ignore_space
setopt hist_verify
setopt inc_append_history
setopt share_history # share command history data
#dirs
setopt autopushd pushdminus pushdsilent pushdtohome pushdignoredups
setopt auto_name_dirs
#appearance
setopt multios
setopt cdablevarS
setopt prompt_subst
#misc
setopt long_list_jobs
#correction
setopt correct_all
#completion
setopt auto_menu         # show completion menu on succesive tab press
setopt complete_in_word
setopt completealiases
setopt always_to_end
#syml
setopt chaselinks
#stop pissing me off when using ! in line
unsetopt banghist    

# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/alex/.zshrc'

# Already in ohmyzsh
#autoload -Uz compinit
#compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall

########
# Key bindings, vi, etc.
autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd 'v' edit-command-line

# create a zkbd compatible hash;
# to add other keys to this hash, see: man 5 terminfo
typeset -A key

key[Home]=${terminfo[khome]}
key[BackSpace]=${terminfo[kbs]}
key[End]=${terminfo[kend]}
key[Insert]=${terminfo[kich1]}
key[Delete]=${terminfo[kdch1]}
key[Up]=${terminfo[kcuu1]}
key[Down]=${terminfo[kcud1]}
key[Left]=${terminfo[kcub1]}
key[Right]=${terminfo[kcuf1]}
key[PageUp]=${terminfo[kpp]}
key[PageDown]=${terminfo[knp]}

# setup key accordingly
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Home]}"    beginning-of-line
[[ -n "${key[BackSpace]}" ]]  &&  bindkey "${key[BackSpace]}" backward-delete-char
[[ -n "${key[BackSpace]}" ]] &&  bindkey -M vicmd "${key[BackSpace]}" backward-delete-char
bindkey '^H' backward-delete-char
bindkey -M vicmd '^H' backward-delete-char
bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char
bindkey -M vicmd "^?" backward-delete-char
[[ -n "${key[End]}"     ]]  && bindkey  "${key[End]}"     end-of-line
[[ -n "${key[Insert]}"  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Insert]}"  overwrite-mode
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"  ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Delete]}"  delete-char
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"  ]]  && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Delete]}"  delete-char

[[ -n "${key[Left]}"    ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Left]}"    backward-char
[[ -n "${key[Right]}"   ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Right]}"   forward-char

[[ -n "${key[Up]}"   ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Up]}"    history-beginning-search-backward && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Up]}"    history-beginning-search-backward
[[ -n "${key[Down]}" ]]  && bindkey  "${key[Down]}"  history-beginning-search-forward && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Down]}"  history-beginning-search-forward

bindkey -M vicmd 'h'  backward-char
bindkey -M vicmd 'l'  forward-char
bindkey -M vicmd '^R' redo
bindkey -M vicmd 'u'  undo
bindkey -M vicmd 'ga' what-cursor-position
bindkey -M vicmd 'v'  edit-command-line


# Finally, make sure the terminal is in application mode, when zle is
# active. Only then are the values from $terminfo valid.
if (( ${+terminfo[smkx]} )) && (( ${+terminfo[rmkx]} )); then
    function zle-line-init () {
        printf '%s' "${terminfo[smkx]}"
    }
    function zle-line-finish () {
        printf '%s' "${terminfo[rmkx]}"
    }
    zle -N zle-line-init
    zle -N zle-line-finish
fi
```

Comment: What happens when you do `Ctrl+R` backward search?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting `HISTFILE` in your zsh configuration really should change to where the history is written *and* from where it is read. It is likely that *oh-my-zsh* sets `HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history` before you set it, in which case the history has already been read from `~/.zsh_history`.

Looking at the *oh-my-zsh* code, there are two ways to solve this:

- set `HISTFILE` before loading *oh-my-zsh*. That is, it has to be set in your `~/.zshrc` before the line containing

  ```
  source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
  ```

  This would be a simple solution, if you only want to change `HISTFILE`.
- overload the `history.zsh` module with your own custom version. *Oh-my-zsh* loads all files matching `$ZSH/lib/*.zsh` (where `$ZSH` usually is `~/.oh-my-zsh`) at startup, unless in `${ZSH_CUSTOM}/lib/` is a file with the same name (`ZSH_CUSTOM` usually is `$ZSH/custom`). The history settings can be found in `$ZSH/lib/history.zsh` and can therefore replaced by `${ZSH_CUSTOM}/lib/history.zsh`.

  If you want to change more of the settings found in `$ZSH/lib/history.zsh` this is probably the way to go. Otherwise you would have to set `HISTFILE` before loading *oh-my-zsh* and everything else after.

---

A way to change `HISTFILE` (temporarily) later in a shell session is

```
fc -p /path/to/new_history
```

This puts the current history on a stack, sets `HISTFILE=/path/to/new_history` and reads the history from that file (if it exists). Any new commands will then also be written to the new `HISTFILE`. You can go back to the original history with `fc -P`.

Comment: Excellent. The `fc -p` solution is the one I use now. I will later dig deeper in the zsh builtins.