# zsh: interpret date in .zsh_history file

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history, python3

I have copied `.zsh_history` file from another session, and I want to inspect it. Normally, if I was inspecting my standard `~/.zsh_history` file, I would just use the zsh built-in command `history`, where I can specify custom date format:

```
$ history -t '(%a) %Y-%b-%d %H:%M' 0
90  (Sat) 2021-Sep-11 17:24  cd ..
91  (Sat) 2021-Sep-11 17:24  ls
92  (Sat) 2021-Sep-11 17:26  run-help history
```

The history command does not seem to have option to specify which file to read. I can simply cat the file, but then I see the non-human readable date format (epoch?):

```
: 1631327094:0;echo
: 1631340742:0;true
```

How could I either interpret the history file using some zsh's function, or if not possible, how could I interpret this using some simple python script, so that I can see date format similar to my history example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps are expressed in the standard [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): as a number of seconds since the epoch, which is 1970-01-01.

```
% TZ=Pacific/Kiritimati date +'(%a) %Y-%b-%d %H:%M' -d @1631327094
(Sat) 2021-Sep-11 16:24
% TZ=Pacific/Kiritimati python -c 'import datetime, sys; print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(sys.argv[1])).strftime("(%a) %Y-%b-%d %H:%M"))' 1631327094
(Sat) 2021-Sep-11 16:24
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change the history file.

```
chmod -w <oldsessionhistfile> # Prevent new entries in it.
fc -p <oldsessionhistfile> # Set new history file
history # Inspect or whatever you want to do
fc -P # Restore previous one
```

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265957/zsh-histfile-still-read-from-zsh-history).